# Which Linux distribution has the most active/recent Ruby support?

Tags: ruby, linux

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 and tried to install Ruby as `apt-get install ruby`. The default version in repositories was 1.8.7, okay, install 1.9.2 manually. Then I'm going for rubygems, download tar file, install rubygems, try to install something with them, zlib-mistake appeared. Found the solution with rvm, didn't help. Now I'm stuck with broken gem command and useless rvm installed.

The question is - which Linux distribution is the most friendly for a Ruby beginner?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS works great; and use rvm as @Teoulas suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution shouldn't matter at all, if you're using [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) (strongly suggested). Otherwise, if you want to have the latest up-to-date packages (including ruby) you could turn to rolling release distros (such as [Archlinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) or [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/)). You can always add other repositories to any distro, and get more updated packages this way, as others suggested for Ubuntu.

Update: It's been years since my original reply. Nowadays, with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), [Podman](https://podman.io/) and [toolbx](https://containertoolbx.org/), the distro itself is even less relevant. With containers, one can set up an isolated Ruby environment and ensure developer-production parity.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

out of the box? Of course, you can also use a community ppa to get 1.9.2 and some common bindings out-of-the-box (so you can work easily with, say, Rails 3.0):

http://www.humbug.in/2010/launchpad-ppa-for-ruby-1-9-2-and-some-ruby-bindings/

Comment: I heard that rails doesn't support ruby 1.9.1

Comment: @Sergey: As has been discussed countless times already (and you can trivially check for yourself in a matter of milliseconds), the current version number of the [`ruby1.9.1` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ruby1.9.1) is 1.9.2-p0 which is not the latest, but not really ancient either.

Answer (score 1):

Many ruby developers use Ubuntu with rvm. The benefit is that you can install multiple versions and switching them is easy.

Furthermore there are many tutorials and help on errors for rvm.

I would suggest to install a VM and copy it, then and try rvm. If you cripple your system just use the copy again until you setup your system correctly.

Once you know your way around you can install ruby on your system or just stick with the VM like many other do.

On the other hand many server use Debian, wich is slightly different than Ubuntu as it uses older stable packages.